# Own defined attribute for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a HTML File, that looks like this:

```
        Input 1: <input type="text" required="false" /><br>
    Input 2: <input type="text" required="true" /> *<br>
    Input 3: <input type="text" required="false" /><br>
    Input 4: <input type="text" required="false" /><br>
    Input 5: <input type="text" required="true" /> *<br>
    Input 6: <input type="text" required="false" /><br>
    Input 7: <input type="text" required="true" /> *<br>
    <input type="button" id="subButton" value="Run" />
```

This is my jQuery-script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#subButton").click(function(){

                    //Copy START
                    var setError = false;
                    $.each($(":input"), function(e){
                        if(($(this).attr("required") == "true") && (this.value == "")){
                            setError = true;
                        }
                    });
                    if(setError != false) alert("Not all required fields are filled");
                    //Copy END

                });
            });
```

If i change the attr to "type", it works if i not fill up every box. But i want to use this with the attribute required.

Any ideas, why it doesn't work?

Thanks for help

Comment: [`required`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text.attrs.required) is a boolean attribute. Setting it to `"false"` is invalid.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `required` in a wrong way. If HTML, it should be this way:

```
<input type="text" required />
```

And if it is XHTML, it should be this way:

```
<input type="text" required="required" />
```

And you need to access it using jQuery using [`$.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop):

```
if($("input").prop("required")) { ... }
```

---

Else, you have the freedom to use `data-*` attributes this way:

```
data-reqd="yes"
```

And access it using:

```
if ($(this).data("reqd") == "yes") { ... }
```

Comment: Wow thanks.. .prop was the solution. You know, I have pretended, so it has to be done like this.

Comment: The all new [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) is there for your help any time. :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
data-required="true/false"
```

then

```
if ($(this).data("required")) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[`required`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute) is an official (not "own defined") attribute of `<input>`s, and it's [boolean](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) - `"false"` is an invalid value. Also, using jQuery's `attr` on this adds some additional quirks, so that you get back the string `"required"`. Better use the `required` property, which really returns a boolean value.

```
Input 1: <input type="text" /><br>
Input 2: <input type="text" required /> *<br>
Input 3: <input type="text" /><br>
Input 4: <input type="text" /><br>
Input 5: <input type="text" required="" /> *<br>
Input 6: <input type="text" /><br>
Input 7: <input type="text" required="required" /> *<br>
<input type="button" id="subButton" value="Run" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#subButton").click(function(){
             var setError = false;
             $(":input").each(function(e){
                 if ( this.required && this.value == "" )
                     setError = true;
                 }
             });
             if ( setError )
                 alert("Not all required fields are filled");
         });
     });
</script>
```